# django orm: retrieve object and check if it has a relation in one query

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have an application where users can set a post as their favorite. Models are defined like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField('Post', through='Favorite', related_name='favorited_by')

class Post(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    body = models.TextField()

class Favorite(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Now I'm looking for an easy way to query a post and at the same time check if the post is favorited by the current user. Currently I'm using the following, far from elegant, solution:

```
query = """
    SELECT p.id, p.body, p.created_by_id, f.created_by_id AS favorited 
        FROM main_post p LEFT OUTER JOIN main_favorite f
        ON 
            p.id = f.post_id AND     
            f.created_by_id = %s
    """;

posts = Post.objects.raw(query, [request.user.userprofile.id])
```

This results in a column named 'favorited' with either a null value if the post is not favorited by the current user or with the id of the current user if the post is favorited.

Is there anyway this could be done simpler and more elegant using django's ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Django provides with the [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) which might be useful in your case. And it is also does the same work in a more elegant way using generic foreign keys for this.

**Check the examples at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/ they are very similar to what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I dont see how. Wouldnt a generic foreign key only be helpful if there would be different types of models that could be marked as favorited? In this app the favorites field of a UserProfile has only Post models and no need for different models.